# Getting result in List[(Char, Int)] instead of List[Product]

Tags: list, scala, types, tuples

I'm trying out the following piece of code in Scala REPL,

```
val a = List(('a',4),('b',8))
val z = ('a',1)
a map (x => if (x._1 == z._1) (x._1, x._2 - z._2) else (z :: a))
```

I'm getting the following output: `List[Product] = List((a,3), List((a,1), (a,4), (b,8)))`

Why am I getting output in `List[Product]` ?

What should I do to get the resultant type of the output be `List[(Char, Int)]` instead of `List[Product]`

Comment: Isn't double-nested lists and `List[(Char, Int)]` at the same time oxymorons?

Comment: Which result do you want to have in concrete, given your values? Note that the if-part and the else part don't match in the returned type. Either you return a new pair, or a List of pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are applying a function to every element in the list `"a"`

In the first iteration you take `(a,4)` and in this case you are applying a function that substract 1 to the second element of the tuple.

The result is `(a,3)`

But in the second element you are using cons operator to "a" so the result of this operation is a new inmmutable list.

```
('a',1) :: List(('a',4),('b',8)) === List((a,1), (a,4), (b,8))
```

IMO what you want as result is:

```
List(('a',3),('b',8))
```

That can be achieved like this:

```
a.map {
    case (z._1, x) => (z._1, x - z._2)
    case x => x
}
```